# How to handle non-ascii characters in content of columns while collecting using Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, utf-8, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, ascii

I have a requirement where I need to collect some columns onto Spark driver and some columns contain non-ascii characters. But while collecting them its gives error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 187: ordinal not in range(128).
```

Any idea how maybe I can apply udf to column content while fetching it and then collect it onto driver?

I am using PySpark for this.

Comment: How do you read the data? If you read them from a file you can define encoding as utf-8 on read

Comment: I am reading data from Hive.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This worked for me :

```
import sys
import codecs
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout)
sys.stderr = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stderr)
```

I found it here https://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2014/01/12/python-unicode-console-output.html